# problems with labelpath asymptote

Tags: asymptote

I would like to write a text along a circumference with Asymptote's module `labelpath3`. Below there is the code:

```
size(200);
import labelpath3;
path3 g = shift(-Z)*unitcircle3;
string txt = "Orizzonte";
draw (g,1bp+red);
draw(labelpath(txt,g,angle=180,optional=rotate(-70,X)*Z));
```

I just started using Asymptote, the code above I saw it in the Asymptote tutorials. This code write a text too big. If I multiply the argument `txt` in `labelpath` for `scale(0.2)` the terminal show me the message:

```
cannot call surface labelpath(string s, path3 p, real angle, triple optional)
with parameters:
(label,path3,int angle, triple optional)
```

Why?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! For scaling of 3D objects you need to use `scale3` instead of `scale`.

Comment: I saw that you posted a comment as an answer. However, I do not understand your comment. 180 degrees also works with my code. And with `texdoc asymptote` you get nice manual.

Answer (score 1):

I could only guess what you want. You need to use `scale3` instead of `scale`. And if you just want to put text on a part of the path, according to the examples on [this site](http://www.piprime.fr/files/asymptote/odoc/index.html) you need to use subpath.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asypictureB}
\begin{document}
\begin{asypicture}{name=AsyPlot}
size(200);
import labelpath3;
path3 g = scale3(0.1)*shift(-Z)*unitcircle3;
string txt = "Orizzonte";
draw (g,1bp+red);
draw(rotate(-40,Z)*labelpath(txt,subpath(g,0,reltime(g,0.4)),angle=-90,optional=rotate(-70,X)*Z));
\end{asypicture} 
\end{document}
```